# Procedure to change a person's designation

Tags: mysql, sql-procedure

People are occasionally moved between different departments. I want to create a procedure that accepts a name (name of person) and a department(department that person is assigned to) and changes the person's department assignment to a new department.

for example:

```
create procedure assign (
in name VARCHAR(256),
in department VARCHAR(256)
)
comment "move work to new department"
BEGIN
   UPDATE name
   SET department = newdepartment
END$$
```

please ask if you need more information for better understanding.

Comment: So basically I want to update a workers designated department, but I don't know how to do this or how it changes a stored name. Something like an Alter table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

create procedure assign (
    in _name VARCHAR(256),    -- use underscore (or some other pattern) to distinguish args
    in _newdepartment VARCHAR(256)
)
BEGIN
   UPDATE Employees  -- need table name
       SET department = _newdepartment
       WHERE name = _name   -- need to specify which row
       ;   -- most statements need a semi-colon terminator.
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```